# Make dynamically ActionMode and Tabs bottom of page

Tags: android, dynamic, menu, actionmode

[image: reference screen]
<sub>(source: [piccy.info](http://i.piccy.info/i9/1cf40da3123e855e2530e3bf86013d1e/1460994507/172350/1026214/question_to_so_android.jpg))</sub>

- 1 page - none of items are marked
- 2 page - two items are marked, actionmode menu present with change "Done" to "Cancel", and other menu is appear on bottom of page

I have next question - if I use ListView and mark with checkbox one or more items, how to **add dynamically** :

1. Action mode menu over ActionBar/ToolBar ?
2. Three tabs bottom of page as reference image above or *another type of menu* as image above ?

And some *additional* questions :

1. How to replace "Done" actionmode button text to custom text, example "Cancel" ?
2. How to change default job of "Done" ? As example I can override BACK button, but how to override "Done" button ?

P.S. I think - exist other way to add these functionality. Thanks for any idea !